# How to properly get `next` to use use overridden instance method `__next__`?

Tags: python, iterator, built-in, instance-methods

Consider the following snippet.

```py
class A:
    def __next__(self):
        return 2

a = A()
print(next(a),a.__next__()) # prints "2,2" as expected
a.__next__ = lambda: 4
print(next(a),a.__next__()) # prints "2,4". I expected "4,4"
```

Clearly, the property `__next__` is updated by the patching, but the inbuilt `next` function does not resolve that.

The [python 3 docs docs on the python datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) that says

> For instance, if a class defines a method named `__getitem__()`, and `x` is an instance of this class, then `x[i]` is roughly equivalent to `type(x).__getitem__(x, i)`.

From this, I came up with a hack as below

```py
class A:
    def next_(self):
        return 2

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next_()

a = A()
print(next(a),a.__next__()) # 2,2
a.next_ = lambda: 4
print(next(a),a.__next__()) # 4,4
```

The code works, but at the expense of another layer of indirection via another `next_`-method.

My question is: What is the proper way to monkey-patch the `__next__` instance method? What is the rationale behind this design in python?

Comment: `A.__next__ = lambda: 4`

Comment: I specifically want to redefine the *instance*, not the *class*, so that is not viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't**. Special methods are **special** they cannot be overridden at the instance level. Period. If you want to "customize" the instance behaviour the correct way to do it is to simply have a proper implementation instead of a bogus implementation that you swap at runtime. *Change the value instead of the method.*

The rationale can be found in [The History of Python - Adding Support for User-defined Classes](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html) at the end of following section:

> ## Special Methods
>
> As briefly mentioned in the last section, one of my main goals was to
>   keep the implementation of classes simple. In most object oriented
>   languages, there are a variety of special operators and methods that
>   only apply to classes. For example, in C++, there is a special syntax
>   for defining constructors and destructors that is different than the
>   normal syntax used to define ordinary function and methods.
>
> I really didn't want to introduce additional syntax to handle special
>   operations for objects. So instead, I handled this by simply mapping
>   special operators to a predefined set of "special method" names such
>   as `__init__` and `__del__`. By defining methods with these names, users
>   could supply code related to the construction and destruction of
>   objects.
>
> I also used this technique to allow user classes to redefine the
>   behavior of Python's operators. As previously noted, Python is
>   implemented in C and uses tables of function pointers to implement
>   various capabilities of built-in objects (e.g., “get attribute”, “add”
>   and “call”). To allow these capabilities to be defined in user-defined
>   classes, I mapped the various function pointers to special method
>   names such as `__getattr__`, `__add__`, and `__call__`. **There is a direct
>   correspondence between these names and the tables of function pointers
>   one has to define when implementing new Python objects in C.**

In summary: types defined in C have a structure that contains pointers to special methods. Guido wanted to keep consistency with types defined in Python and so their special methods end up being used at the class level.

Could the implementation always follow the lookup order? Yes... at a **huge** cost in speed, since now even the C code would have to first perform a dictionary lookup on the instance to ensure whether or not a special method is defined and call that. Given that special methods are called often, especially for built-in types, it makes sense to just have a direct pointer to the function in the class. The behaviour of the python side is just consistent with this.

Python was never bright in the performance sector. Your suggested implementation would run extremely slowly, especially 20 years ago when it was design on way less powerful machines and when JITs were extremely rare and not so well understood (compared to the present).

Comment: Perfect! Coming to python from other languages it takes time to understand what is a pythonic way to do things, and why you should *not* do other things. This helps a lot along the way! :)